# Doctrine 2.1 - getting entities restrictions

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two classes:
**Game**

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="games") */
class Game {
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=100) */
    protected $title;

    /** @ManyToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="games") */
    protected $news;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->news = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    public function setTitle($val) { $this->title = trim($val); }
    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }

    public function getNews() { return $this->news; }
    public function setNews($value) {
        $except_txt = 'Jedna z przesłanych wartości nie jest instancją klasy News!';

        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $v) {
                if($v instanceof News) $this->news->add($v);
                else throw new Exception($except_txt);
            }
        } else {
            if($value instanceof News) $this->news->add($value);
            else throw new Exception($except_txt);
        }
    }
}
```

**News**:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="news") */
class News {
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=100) */
    protected $title;

    /** @Column(type="text") */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="news")
     * @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $author;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $add_date;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="news")
     * @JoinTable(name="news_game",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $games;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->add_date = new DateTime();
        $this->games = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    # ID methods
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    # TITLE methods
    public function setTitle($val) { $this->title = $val; }
    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }

    # CONTENT methods
    public function setContent($val) { $this->content = $val; }
    public function getContent() { return $this->content; }

    # AUTHOR methods
    public function setAuthor($val) { if($val instanceof User) $this->author = $val; }
    public function getAuthor() { return $this->author; }

    # ADD DATE methods
    public function getAddDate() { return $this->add_date; }

    # GAMES methods
    public function setGames($value) {
        $except_txt = 'Jedna z przesłanych wartości nie jest instancją klasy Game!';

        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $v) {
                if($v instanceof Game) $this->games->add($v);
                else throw new Exception($except_txt);
            }
        } else {
            if($value instanceof Game) $this->games->add($value);
            else throw new Exception($except_txt);
        }
    }
    public function getGames() { return $this->games; }
}
```

And this code:

```
$i = 1;
if($game->getNews()->count() > 0) {
    foreach($game->getNews()->getValues() as $v) {
        $news_list.= '<p>News '.$i.'</p>';
        $i++;
        if($i == 6) break;
    }
}
```

**1st question**:
Does Doctrine will download from database all News related with particular Game, or only those 5, which I need?

**2nd question**:
How Can I download 5 News with Doctrine's separate query without having `NewsGames` class?

Answer (score 5):

Pre answering:
Before I start to answer, you don't really need to getValues() from the News ArrayCollection.
All you can do is:

```
foreach ($game->getNews() as $news) {
    // Do whatever you want with associated News object.
}
```

Answer #1: 
Doctrine 2 will only retrieve the News that are associated to this given Game, nothing else.

Answer #2:
You don't need the NewsGames object. Be aware that what you have mapped is a join table, so in OO perspective the object never exists.

Cheers,

Guilherme Blanco

Comment: About `Answer #1` - Yes, but if I want only, for example, 5 News from database (and the whole amount of them is 10)? This `$game->getNews()` will download all 10 News, right?

Comment: When working with `EXTRA_LAZY` collections, you can avoiding loading them all by using `foreach($game->getNews()->slice($start, $end) as $news) { /* ... */ }`. For more awesome stuff check the `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` interface.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know :). Thanks!